# noSuchBeanDefinationException - Springboot Junit 5

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit

I am trying write some test case but it's failing with `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException`.
Can you please help me to understand the problem?

```
@Service
public class PersonService implements IPersonService{

    @Autowired
    PersonRepo repo;

    @Autowired
    RetrievePersonData retrievePersonData;

    @Autowired
    PersonDataMerger personDataMerger;

    @Autowired
    Clock clock;

    // Implementations

}
```

Now inside those `RetrievePersonData`, `PersonDataMerger` there are several other classes *autowired*.
Below is my test class

```
    @SpringBootTest
    @ContextConfiguration(classes={ServiceProperties.class, AppConfig.class, EncryptionUtils.class}) 
    @ActiveProfile("test")
    public class PersonServiceTest {
    
        @Autowired
        PersonService service;
    
        @Test
        public void getDataTest(){
        // call PersonService to get the data and match
    }
 }
```

But it's failing `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException` - for `PersonService`

I am not able to figure it out what am I missing?

Comment: Use `@InjectMocks` and other `Mockito` annotations for JUnit tests. You don't need real beans to perform testing !

Comment: What is the structure of your project? Does your main class containing the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation is on top of all your packages?